# Node JS Inspect shows property has value but inspecting property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, coffeescript

I'm working on a Node JS app, using Coffeescript and Mongoose with a MongoDB database.

I have a Mongoose model like this:

```
Client = mongoose.model 'Client', mongoose.Schema

    # Basics
    name: String
    email: String
    api_key: String

    # Modules enabled / disabled
    modules: Object

    # Settings for modules
    reporting: Object
    filter: Object
    templates: Object
    datatypes: Object
```

The modules property is an object containing keys with a boolean indicating whether or not a module should be loaded (see the console.log output a bit further in this post). The four properties below that are the settings for the specific modules.

When my app starts, I load this information for the current user, and assign the data to a config variable like this:

```
config.name = clients[0].name
config.api_key = clients[0].api_key

config.modules =
    reporting_enabled: clients[0].modules.reporting
    filter_enabled: clients[0].modules.filter
    templates_enabled: clients[0].modules.templates
    datatypes_enabled: clients[0].modules.datatypes
```

Now the first three of these modules work perfectly. I coded them about a week ago and nothing was wrong. But I'm adding the datatypes module now, and I'm running into a very strange problem.

Whenever I try to access the `clients[0].datatypes` property it returns `undefined` but when I do `console.log clients[0]` it will show me all the properties, and their values, including datatypes.

Part of the output of `console.log clients[0]`:

```
modules: 
 { datatypes: true,
   templates: true,
   filter: false,
   reporting: true },
reporting: 
 { email_interval: 2,
   name: '___',
   email: '___',
   send_email: true },
filter: {},
templates: { cms: { contacts: [Object] } },
datatypes: { cms: { contacts: [Object] } }
```

So as you see, there's all the properties including datatypes. Of these I can access the modules, reporting, filter and templates properties without any problem (using `clients[0].modules` for example), but when I want to access the datatypes property `clients[0].datatypes` it will return `undefined`.

I have triple-checked that I'm writing 'datatypes' correctly, and that it's not an async function that messes with me. I put the log right before the line where I actually want to use .datatypes, and no async stuff is going on at that point, so that isn't it. I tried some other things, changing the loading order etc, but nothing works.

```
console.log clients[0]
console.log clients[0].datatypes
```

That first line outputs my whole object including the datatypes property. The second one keeps saying `undefined`.

I think this may have something to do with Node or Mongoose, or it's one of those Javascript quirks, or perhaps (just as likely) it's just me being an idiot and messing something up. I really don't know and I've been searching for a solution for around two hours now, done something of a hundred google searches, went digging through StackOverflow and other websites, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem and couldn't fix it myself. Does anyone here know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: No async functions running that could influence the `clients` array. There's a Mongoose .find that gets the client data, and this code is in its callback function. I use the various properties in `clients` without any problems, before and after where I put the console.log bit. Also, by live reference do you mean that values printed to the terminal will update as clients[0] changes? Cause I have never seen that happen? I'm not talking about the browser Javascript debugger window by the way, this is a Node app that I'm running in the terminal on my Mac.

Comment: What can I do to find out if that's the case? I don't think that's it though, I added the property through the Mongolab online interface just like the rest of the data and it's only that one property that's causing issues.

Comment: I tried some more things, I finally got it working by calling .toObject() on the Mongoose object that I received. I don't understand why the other properties worked perfectly without that and this one wouldn't, but I did manage to fix the problem. @muistooshort thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem, the fix for me was to call [`.toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on the Mongoose result: `client[0] = client[0].toObject()`. This transforms the Mongoose object into a regular object.

To me it is still a bit of a mystery why all the other properties could be addressed fine without this, but that one property wouldn't. But `.toObject()` solved this problem for me.